# dynamic delegate to pass a method as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

Is there any way to use DLR to reference a method in C#?

In dynamic languages like JavaScript or Python I could easily pass a method as an argument to another method. In C# being statically typed language, I either use `Delegate` type which needs lots of casting:

```
public static void AddMethod(Delegate del)
{
    // implementation
}
```

and then use casting whenever I call this method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddMethod(new Func<object, bool>(Test));
}

public static bool Test(object obj)
{
    return true;
}
```

Or, I need to define dozens of overloads to satisfy any method calls:

```
public static void AddMethod<TResult>(Func<TResult> method)
{
}

public static void AddMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> method)
{
}

public static void AddMethod<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> method)
{
}

public static void AddMethod<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> method)
{
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to define an argument as a placeholder for all other methods? (I'm trying to avoid `MethodInfo` or other `Reflection` stuff here)

I was trying something like this:

```
public delegate dynamic DynamicDelegate(params dynamic[] args);

public static void AddMethod(DynamicDelegate method)
{
}
```

But the compiler doesn't seem to accept a statically typed method for a dynamically declared delegates!

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Say that you can pass a "dynamic delegate" to another method, what is that other method going to do with it? If you want to invoke it, you either have to know how the signature of that method looks, or you implicitly have to supply the argument values as well so the "other method" doesn't have to know about them (which is usally done through a lambda, see L.B.'s post). Or is the "other method" only going to pass the delegate on?

Comment: You are right, what I am trying to do is to extract the signature and the information of the registered method, for further call. I'm trying to create a simple Evaluation or better say, dynamic code generation that lets user to write his own C# code using the predefined methods

Comment: All right, but who is going to invoke the passed method? Will it be your code that invokes the user-supplied code as if it were a plugin? Or will it be the user's own code, where your code merely acts as a temporary storage for the delegate until the user is allowed to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple `Action`

```
void AddMethod(Action action) //or void AddMethod(Func<TResult> fxn)
{
}
```

and call as

```
AddMethod(()=>Test(obj));
```

or

```
AddMethod(()=>Test(obj1,obj2));
```

--EDIT--

```
AddMethod(() => Math.Max(1,3));  
AddMethod(() => (int)Math.Sqrt(4));
AddMethod(() => new int[]{8,5,6}.Min())

void AddMethod(Func<int> fxn)
{
     int i = fxn() * fxn();  // <---
}
```

Comment: Using Action means that I'm actually calling the method, however what I'm looking for is passing the method as an argument, I need to get reference of the method for further callback

Comment: @KamyarNazeri See my edit. `Using Action means that I'm actually calling the method`  Not exactly, unless you call it explicitly.

Comment: That's right, but this is exactly what I meant by "defining dozens of overloads", this way I have to define lots of overloads to satisfy any method with any signature

Comment: @KamyarNazeri I don't get you. For example, in the second part you can pass any function that returns an int.

Comment: this implementation is actually correct for int, how about a method that takes an argument? a method that takes 2 arguments or 3 or 4? I'm trying to be as abstract as possible to be able to register any method with any signature, this way I have to define lots of methods which take Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, ...>, the same goes with Action<T1,T2,T3,...>

Comment: @KamyarNazeri see the edited part, I passed 3 functions  returning int(one takes 1 int(*Sqrt*) the other 2(*Max*), and the last one takes an IEnumerable<int> (*Min()*)) to AddMethod

Comment: @L.B  He doesn't want something that returns an int.  He wants a fully abstract method that can take any arguments of any type and return any object of any type.

Comment: @J... `int` is just an example. All the functions in the question returns `TResult` (only differ in parameters) therefore i gave that example. `Action` can be used too if the return type also is unknown

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET doesn't allow delegates with an unknown parameter syntax (this would approximate C void pointers, which is not something you want in a type-safe language), the closest thing that allows a variable argument list would be to pass an array of object arguments (i.e. `object MyMethod(params object[] args))`.
However, since this array is also an object reference, you can suffice with a single object reference:

```
object MyMethod(object arg))
```

The .NET framework also does this, see e.g. the [ParameterizedThreadStart delegate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

So the basic idea is that you require that the user writes his code as a method that matches the above signature, and in turn it can receive any variable list of arguments of any type or size.

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
    Logger coreLogger;
    Logger coreErrorLogger;

    public Core()
    {
        PassByReference timestamp = new PassByReference(Timestamp);

        coreLogger = Logger.GetLogger("LiTHiuM Core");
        coreLogger.SetFormat("[{0}][LiTHiuM Core]: ", timestamp);
        coreLogger.AddLogger(Log);


        coreErrorLogger = Logger.GetLogger("LiTHiuM Core Error");
        coreErrorLogger.SetFormat("[{0}][LiTHiuM Core (ERROR)]: ", timestamp);
        coreErrorLogger.AddLogger(Error);

    }

    public string Timestamp(params dynamic[] args)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

```
    public delegate dynamic Reference(params dynamic[] args);

    public class PassByReference
    {
        Reference reference;

        public PassByReference(Reference reference)
        {
            this.reference = reference;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.reference().ToString();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Logger
    {

        static Dictionary<string, Logger> logFormatDict = new Dictionary<string, Logger>();
        private List<LoggerDelegate> loggerDelegates = new List<LoggerDelegate>();
        public static Logger GetLogger(string name)
        {
            if (logFormatDict.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return logFormatDict[name];
            }
            else
            {
                var newLogFormat = new Logger(name, "");
                logFormatDict.Add(name, newLogFormat);
                return newLogFormat;
            }
        }

        private event LoggerDelegate loggingEvent;
        private Logger(string name, string format, params dynamic[] args)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.format = format;
            this.args = args;
        }
        public void AddLogger(LoggerDelegate logger)
        {
            if (!loggerDelegates.Contains(logger))
            {
                loggingEvent += logger;
                loggerDelegates.Add(logger);
            }
        }

        public void RemoveLogger(LoggerDelegate logger)
        {
            if (loggerDelegates.Contains(logger))
            {
                loggingEvent -= logger;
                loggerDelegates.Remove(logger);
            }
        }

        public void Log(string text, params dynamic[] args)
        {
            this.Invoke(String.Format(text, args));
        }

        public void Invoke(string text, params dynamic[] args)
        {
            loggingEvent.Invoke(this.ToString() + text, args);
        }


        public void SetFormat(string format, params dynamic[] args)
        {
            this.args = args;
            this.format = format;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        string format;
        dynamic[] args;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format(format, args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.